# Sam local template handler within sub directory

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a file called index.js within a sub-folder called api. The template.yaml is in the root folder. I am trying to add the handler (index.js) to the template but get the following error -

```
Mounting /Users/......./services/api as /var/task:ro inside runtime container
START RequestId: 62e6c91c-8c27-167a-d34c-b2e7aab1d11e Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/appLpVideoList.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

The template.yaml looks like -

```
VideoList:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: api/
      Events:
        EventDetail:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /videos
            Method: get
      Environment:
          Variables:
            NODE_ENV: local
```

Comment: Can you share what you are actually trying to do? Do you execute a command which results in this error? Or is the error thrown when calling the Lambda function e.g. using the /videos path?

Comment: I run sam local start-api and then hit the /videos path using postman.

Answer (score -1):

So instead of using sam local I used serverless-offline and it solved my issue. U can find the details about serverless-offline here -

https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline